# set image path in jsp

Tags: css, jsp, servlets

i have one jsp page which is in **jsp/test.jsp** folder ,in this jsp i am including another jsp
that is **header.jsp**  that is not in jsp folder in this page i am giving image path like **imges/logo.png**

Now my problem is that image logo is not displaying in test.jsp,if i change path to **../imges/logo.png**

it is display in **test.jsp** but not showing in another jsp which is outside jsp(foldername) folder

please help me to solve the problem

in short i want to display that logo whether my jsp page is inside folder or not

Here is my jsp page

```
       test.jsp

          <%@include file="../Header.jsp"%>
```

Header.jsp

```
   <a href="##"><img
     src="imges/logo.png"
   alt=""
   align="left"
```

/>

Comment: including jsp does not mean that that page is included. Simply the code of the header.jsp is added to the test.jsp which works fine with ../images/logo.png, while for the jsps you are using outside jsp folder, you need to give images/logo.png

Comment: You can make it relative to the server root `/appname/images/logo.png`